# Why only the called activity's shared element enter transition run?

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I tried to add my custom shared element transition in my app, and I make it work on some different modes in different activity. But in my test, only the called activity's enter transition is executed.

This is my code in the calling activity A:

```
    TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
    set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
    set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
    PortalHeaderBackgroundTransition back = new PortalHeaderBackgroundTransition();
    back.setMode(0);
    set.addTransition(back);
    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(set);

    set = new TransitionSet();
    set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
    set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
    back = new PortalHeaderBackgroundTransition();
    back.setMode(1);
    set.addTransition(back);
    getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(set);
```

This is my code in the called activity B:

```
    TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
    set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
    set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
    PortalHeaderBackgroundTransition back = new PortalHeaderBackgroundTransition();
    back.setMode(2);
    set.addTransition(back);
    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(set);

    set = new TransitionSet();
    set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER);
    set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());
    back = new PortalHeaderBackgroundTransition();
    back.setMode(3);
    set.addTransition(back);
    getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(set);
```

I add breakpoint in my PortalHeaderBackgroundTransition, whenever the A call B or B back to A, only the mode 2 transition is executed.

Why does this happen? And when does the other transition to be executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When activity `A` starts activity `B`, the following events occur:

1. `A`'s exit shared element transition is run.
2. `B`'s enter shared element transition is run.

When `B` returns to `A`, the following events occur:

1. `B`'s return shared element transition is run (if no return transition is specified, `B`'s enter shared element transition will be used instead).
2. `A`'s reenter shared element transition is run (if no reenter transition is specified, `A`'s exit shared element transition will be used instead).

So to answer your question, `A`'s enter shared element transition is never executed because that is the way activity transitions work. :)

Comment: But why the A's exit exit transition do not run?

Comment: It doesn't matter. All you need is to set the enter transition on activity `B` and you should be all set. For more information, check out [this blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/01/activity-fragment-shared-element-transitions-in-depth-part3a.html).

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I am not sure why I could never wrap my head around this but now I can see why some transitions did not work properly in the past :) @AlexLockwood, when or how would be the best way to replace let's say, for example; B's return or A's reenter? In other words, the proper way to remove or modify the shared element(s) before returning back to A.

Comment: For some reason both the SharedElementEnterTransition and SharedElementReturnTransition listeners are getting called when going from Activity A to B.  I thought only the SharedElementEnterTransition listener should be called.  How do you fix this?

Comment: @toobsco42 your problem is worthy of its own question, though it's possible that the problem has already been asked. Such a thing will happen if the shared element exit transition of A is the same object as the shared element enter transition of B; this can be the case if, for example, you define the transition in your theme and it's the same transition reference.